# Copying an input file from a given line and colum number

Tags: python

I am a novice and very new to programming in Python.  I've been working on a Python program (an old version 2.5.2) for for my job.    It is supposed to pass two test conditions to find the beginning of  data that is desired.  The code below does work for this.

It's then supposed to write a file with the information found by the tests, starting at line nr, 10th position, all the way to the /eof marker.  The code that follows is, no doubt, somewhat incomplete, but illustrates the route I'm trying to follow.

I keep getting a "value error: mixing iterations and read methods would lose data" when trying to use the approach I'm following.  I don't fully understand what specifically is causing this error to occur.  Any ideas or suggestion would be much appreciated.  By the way, I can't use ideas the incorporate next(). Thanks.

```
import sys, os
none = " "
previous = none

sys.argv[1]  
numbers = sys.argv[1]
f = open(numbers,'r')  

for nr, line in enumerate(f):
    if line[:8]=="03 00 01":  ### First test condition
    if previous[0:7] =="/origin" and line[0:8]=="03 00 01":  ### Second test conditions.
        lines = f.readlines()  ### Reads everything in file and store in a list.
        begin_at = 10  ### Begins at 10th position in file line.
        for i in range( begin_at, len(lines) ):
            print lines[i]

    previous = line ### Contents of previous line
```

Comment: Post full traceback, also you are initializing `previous` to `None`, and then attempting to slice it `previous[0:7]`.

Comment: @kroolik actually it's `none` and the OP has initialised it to `' '`... Strange... but...

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice! First time seeing someone defining a `none` variable.

Comment: Traceback: File "p9.py, line in 15 in <module> lines = f.readlines()  # read everthin in the file and store it in a list.  ValueError:  Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data.

Comment: @user2994541 you can [edit] your question to include information

Comment: Sorry about weird initialize.  The only reason I left it that way was that I was following coding techniques used in other parts of the script.  Given that having to use version 2.5.2, I had to try some variations for initialization until I found something that did not generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because you are using

`for nr, line in enumerate(f):` and `lines = f.readlines()` simultaneously.

Actually when you use enumerate in for loop:

=> `for nr, line in enumerate(f):`

then you have already read a line from file in variable `line` and then you again read the file inside the loop in variable `lines`

=> `lines = f.readlines()`

this may cause your data to be lost because you are changing the position of filepointer `f` 
and during the next iteration it will not be where it was supposed to be.(most possibly one line ahead)

So either Remove this line [`lines = f.readlines()`] or do this:

```
while True:
    line=f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're looping over the file with `for nr, line in enumerate(f)` and then you've got `lines = f.readlines()` in there... Here's another approach that sticks to iterating over lines only, and doesn't require loading the remaining lines into memory.

```
from itertools import islice, izip, tee, dropwhile

try:
    fin = open('input')
    fout = open('output', 'w')
    fst, snd = tee(fin)
    snd.next()
    dropwhile(lambda L: not (L[0].startswith('/origin') and L[1].startswith('03 00 01')), izip(fst, snd)).next()
    fout.writelines(islice(fin, 10, None))
except StopIteration:
    print "Looks like we didn't find data to use..."
finally:
    fin.close()
    fout.close()
```

We skip over the file while the lines don't meet the criteria, then from that point, we skip 10 lines, and write the lines from that point to the end of the file to the output

Comment: I will check this approach.  I'm sorry for being unclear, but I ment that the data starts at the 10th position on line nr, and then every line after that.

Comment: @user2994541 so, are you saying you can just skip the first 9 lines then? If so, I fail to see why the additional checks?